# How can I stop a .py script that is triggered by some parent .py script without kiiling parent .py?

Tags: python, sys

**[PROBLEM]**
I want to stop a .py script that is triggered by some parent .py script without kiiling parent .py  ?

**I have tried:**
- sys.exit()
- sys.exit(0)
- quit().
All of these will kill both scripts.

Comment: How you call 2nd script? import? os.system?

Comment: @Ali. I called it via import.

Comment: do you just call a function or use threading?

Comment: I call all the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to put all your code in functions, then you can easily call return to exit without missing anything.
file 1:

```
import x
def t():
    x.a()
    print "we still in parent"
t()
```

file 2:

```
def a():
    print "we want to exit here!"
    return
```